# Loose users if upgrading app to newer Android version?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Google Play targeting minimum Android 2.2. Now I want to upgrade the app to at least Android 4.0. I know I have at least one user who is using Android 2.2. What will happen to this user, will he/she still be able to use the app but without the new features or will I loose this user/customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He/she will not receive the update, but will still be able to use the app as long as it is backwards compatible

Comment: How do I make it backwards compatible? My plan was to just change this in the manifest: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" /> to a higher number. I guess that is not enough?

Comment: That's enough. I meant if you're using your own API or something like that, it will need to keep supporting the old app version (which will be on the pre 4.0 devices)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I'm just checking. If the user with Andr 2.2 deletes the app he/she can still download it again from Google Play?

Comment: I believe he/she can reinstall it , but new users will not be able to do so.

Comment: Great, that was helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this page from Android on the topic: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Teeh user will still be able to use the app (if it is backwards compatible with your backend), but the user will not recieve any updates.